# Access Denied in Java While FileOprations

Tags: java, permissions, fileinputstream, windows-11

This was error anyone can solve? In win 11:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\ASUS
> LAPTOP\eclipse-workspace\Aditya.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\JobPortalFinalProj\imgdb
> (Access is denied)

To solve this and get ouputstream? Input running stage.

Comment: `Access is denied`. Why are you assuming that the error message is lying to you? That is a very tiresome and bizarre way to code. Assume error messages are accurate until you have extensive proof otherwise. Thus, the fix - adjust the access rights. Check each folder and the file itself.

Comment: folder loc are correct but in propertiess it says read only prmisoon as folloewd in conole it says access is denied